# QTabWidget.setFixedWidth() for some tab but not all

Tags: python, pyqt, size, qtabwidget, qsizepolicy

My QTabWidget has 4 tabs, the first is fullscreen all other use a fixed Width.

I use a signal to know which tab is used:

```
self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(function)
```

```
def function:
    if self.tabWidget.currentIndex():
        self.tab_widget.setFixedWidth(300)
    else:
        # self.tab_widget.setNotFixedSize()
        # I don't know what to write here
        # I only want my Widget use maximum place
```

When I launch my app I see first tab which is OK (almost fullscreen), if I click on second, widget apply new size and if I come back to first tab, QTabWidget keep wrong size.

Comment: You could set it to the size of your monitor, if nothing else.

Comment: From an UX point of view, I'd say you that having an interface that radically changes its size when switching tab is *terrible*. That said, it's not really clear what you're expecting from the *other* tabs (those that don't have a manually fixed size): should they shrink to a size minimal enough to show their contents?

Comment: my first tab is an overview, it displays 1-2-3-4-5... drones in one QWidget, after this first, all other display each drone individual information and does not need all window size (i need the window right part to display another information). That's why for the first tab i'd like it takes maximum size as it does when I launch my app, I would like to give it back its first behaviour

Comment: @q7frkz please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using setMaximumWidth() > window_size, my first tab retreive natural behaviour (it changes size with window resize)